# Docker Run Post Script not working after dotnet run

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

We are creating a docker image for our Console Application. The Console Application does some background tasks and create a JSON file. The JSON file needs to be used after the dotnet application completes the execution.

The way we are creating the docker file is, the Entry point is set to a bash script and the dotnet application gets invoked from within the shell script.

The docker file is as below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["bash","startup.sh"]
```

The Startup script is as below:

```
#!/bin
echo "Starting dot net console app"
dotnet ConsoleApp4.dll
```

The dotnet console application is just going to print `Hello world` to the console. The docker run command runs perfectly fine with all the above settings.

If we change the startup script as below, then the docker run commands errors our while trying to run the dotnet console app.

```
#!/bin
echo "Starting dot net console app"
dotnet ConsoleApp4.dll
echo "Completed execution"
```

Below is the error which we get while running the docker:

```
Starting dot net console app
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
' does not exist.tion 'ConsoleApp4.dll
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
      Install a .NET SDK from:
        https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
Completed execution
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Might you have accidentally edited the script in a way that inserted DOS line endings?  If there's a hidden carriage-return character U+000D after the `ConsoleApp4.dll` file name that could produce an error that looks like what you've shown.

Comment: How should I give the carriage return in shell script?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the comment. It really helped me to think in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This was the issue with the carriage return character. If we use `;` character at the end of the statement this should work. See below:

```
#!/bin
echo "Starting dot net console app"; dotnet ConsoleApp4.dll; echo "Completed execution"
```